# Remove duplicate recipients from email draft (in Gmail)

Tags: email, gmail

When copying & pasting email addresses into the recipients list in Gmail, how can I remove duplicate email addresses (if the copied list contains duplicates)?

Comment: directly no, but you can use spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paste them first into a tool like [this one](https://www.wordcharactercount.com/remove-duplicate-words/) or [others](https://www.google.de/search?q=remove%20duplicate%20words%20online). It's not entirely safe to put private info into online tools, but you can save such a webpage to disk and use the tool offline.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Gmail group and copy the recipients inside,
then clean up on any duplicates:

[image]